# Kiel oni tradukus «make a friend»?

Tags: phrase-requests

Ĉu estas internacie kompreneble se mi diras «fari amikon» por signifi ke mi faris ion por ekhavi novan amikon? Aŭ ĉu oni komprenus ke mi mem kreis la amikon kiel Frankenstein? Ĉu estas pli bona maniero por esprimi tion?

Answer (score 8):

Tiu estas bona demado.

Du personoj povas "fariĝi amikoj" sed ĉu oni povas "fari novan amikon."

Oni povas fari la amikojn feliĉaj...
Oni povas fari el malamiko amikon...

Mi trovis la jenajn vortojn ĉe "novaj amikoj"

- trovi
- renkonti
- ekhavi

Cetere, mi trovis la jenan frazon en Monato.

- Ni sekvu tiun direkton, kaj faru amikojn en suda Azio.

Se oni povas fari el nekonato amikon, mi pensas ke "fari amikojn en suda Azio" ja estas bona.

Comment: Kion vi pensas pri amikiĝi? Grupo->grupiĝi (iĝi grupo) amiko->amikiĝi (iĝi amiko) Ni amikiĝis antaŭ multaj jaroj

Comment: Amikigxi estas bona vorto, sed mi ne vidas kiel tio povus esti "make a friend."

Comment: Ĝi ne estas rekta traduko de la signifo sed oni povas diri mi amikiĝis kun iu hodiaŭ kaj tio pli-malpli signifas i made a friend today

Comment: Nu, "mi amikigxis kun iu nova" aux "mi kaj iu farigxis amikoj" ja havas similan signifon, sed miaopinie ili estas nenecese pezaj.

Answer (score 6):

> Aŭ ĉu oni komprenus ke mi mem kreis la amikon kiel Frankenstein?

Laŭ mi, jes. Vi kreus amikon kiel Frankenstein.

El la tekstaro:

- 1 trafo - "far[uiao]s amik"
- 0 trafo - "far[uiao]s novaj*n amik"
- 3 trafoj - "trov[uiao]s amik"
- 1 trafo - "trov[uiao]s novaj*n amik"
- 1 trafo - "ekhav[uiao]s amik"
- 1 trafo - "ekhav[uiao]s novaj*n amik"
- 58 trafoj - "amiki[ĝg]"

Do, la plej bona estas **amikiĝi**. Ekzemploj el la tekstaro:

- Mi tuj amikiĝis kun diverse viroj de Francujo....
- Ne amikiĝu kun homo kolerema...
- Ni amikiĝis.
- Bob kaj li amikiĝis antaŭ longe en la urbego...
- Lia instruisto amikiĝis kun Filono...

Vi povas diri "Mi amikiĝis kun iu / li / homo / viro / persono".

Comment: Unuopaj vortoj kompreneble estas pli facile troveblaj en Tekstaro ol frazoj. Via metodo, ekzemple, maltrafis "ekhavi tian amikon". "Farigxi amikoj" (en diversaj formoj) ankaux estas suficxe ofta frazo en Tekstaro.